# Without changing html make it look like a `table`

Tags: html, css

Having such html as in the picture on the left, is it possible to change its appearance so that it looks like in the picture on the right (the width of the first column is equal to the maximum width of the content inside it)? Without using javascriptm changing only css. And without using `min-wdith`, because the width of the content in the first column is unknown, the backend can send different data.

If `.option` elements were not wrapped in `.list-item` elements, it would be possible to apply `display: table-cell` to `.option-col` element and `display: table-row` to `.option` elements. But unfortunately I can't change html. Please, help.

[image]

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.option {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

.option-col {
  color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.option-col + .option-col {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.option-col:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">BEN</div>
      <div class="option-col">
        Has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
        took
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">FOOBARZ</div>
      <div class="option-col">Many desktop publishing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Withotu changing the HTML markup (which you should) there is no other way then to hard code the width of the first columns. Without scripting no element is able to get the width of another element (not a direct sibling or child) and set their own width according to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

A table can have many "bodies", so you can use `display: table-row-group` in your case. Example below:

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: table;
}

.list-item {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.option {
  display: table-row;
}

.option-col {
  color: green;
  display: table-cell;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.option-col + .option-col {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.option-col:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">BEN</div>
      <div class="option-col">
        Has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
        took
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">FOOBARZ</div>
      <div class="option-col">Many desktop publishing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">FOOBARZ 123</div>
      <div class="option-col">Many desktop publishing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

Or you can use [`display: contents;`](https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents) to "*skip*" an element in the nesting structure. Example below:

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: table;
}

.list-item {
  display: contents;
}

.option {
  display: table-row;
}

.option-col {
  color: green;
  display: table-cell;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.option-col + .option-col {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.option-col:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">BEN</div>
      <div class="option-col">
        Has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
        took
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">FOOBARZ</div>
      <div class="option-col">Many desktop publishing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">FOOBARZ 123</div>
      <div class="option-col">Many desktop publishing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 3:**

If you need a solution without using table elements (`display: table;`, `display: table-row`, `display: table-cell` and others), you can use [CSS Grid](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) in combination with `display: contents`, with this combination you implement a subgrid. Example below:

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto; /* set columns */
}

.list-item, .option {
  display: contents;
}

.option-col {
  color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.option-col + .option-col {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.option-col:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">BEN</div>
      <div class="option-col">
        Has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
        took
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">FOOBARZ</div>
      <div class="option-col">Many desktop publishing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-col">FOOBARZ 123</div>
      <div class="option-col">Many desktop publishing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed! :) Never heard of `display: contents`, I wonder now if using ` display: table-cell;` is the only option, or it is achievable with some new attributes I don't know of yet...

Comment: @bapafes482, I added solution №3 to my answer, which relies on CSS Grid and `display: contents`, but without using `display: table-cell`.